# zclip copy next text present in element

Tags: jquery, text, copy, jquery-selectors, zclip

I would like to copy text present in the next element but it doesn't work normaly :
http://jsfiddle.net/tj7ZX/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.copy').zclip({
        path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $(this).next().text(),
        beforeCopy: function () {
            $(this).next().css('background-color', 'grey');
            $(this).children().css('background-position', '-108px -90px');
        },
        afterCopy: function () {
            $(this).children().css('background-position', '-54px -37px');
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following statement:

```
copy: $(this).next().text()
```

It will be applied **once** when you call `zclip`. At that point in time, `this` equals to `document`. In other words, as soon as the page is ready, every `.copy` gets told to copy **the text of `document`'s next sibling**, which naturally doesn't exist.

What we need to do is pass `copy` a function, in which we can dynamically grab the next element's text whenever `.copy` is clicked on:

```
copy: function() {
    return $(this).next().text();
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9E8z5/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try a selector in place of $(this) in `copy: $(this).next().text()`.

Comment: There are multiple links to which the copy function is applied. A constant selector can't determine which link the user clicked on.